# small php code for detecting real search spiders from a spammer

Tags: php, bots

hi I just want your opinions  about this code I found on a website for detect real search spiders from spammer is it good?? and do you have any recommendations for other scripts or methods for this subject

```
<?php 
$ua = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

$spiders=array('msnbot','googlebot','yahoo');

$pattern=array("/\.google\.com$/","/search\.live\.com$/","/\.yahoo\.com$/");

for($i=0;$i < count($spiders) and $i < count($pattern);$i++)

{

  if(stristr($ua, $spiders[$i])){

    //it's pretending to be MSN's bot or Google's bot

    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    $hostname = gethostbyaddr($ip);



    if(!preg_match($pattern[$i], $hostname))

    {

      //the hostname does not belong to either live.com or googlebot.com.

      //Remember the UA already said it is either MSNBot or Googlebot.

      //So it's a spammer.

      echo "spammer";

      exit;

    }

    else{

      //Now we have a hit that half-passes the check. One last go:

      $real_ip = gethostbyname($hostname);

      if($ip != $real_ip){

        //spammer!

        echo "Please leave Now spammr";

        break;

      }

      else{

        //real bot

      }

    }

  }

  else

  {

    echo "hello user";

  }

}
```

note: it used user agent switcher with this code and it worked perfectly but am not sure if it will work in real world, so what do you think??

Comment: Please edit your question and fix the complete lack of indenting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What would keep a spammer from simply giving an *entirely correct* user agent string?

I think this is fairly pointless. You would have to at least compare IP ranges (or their name servers) as well in order to get reliable results. This is possible for Google:

[Google Webmaster Central: How to verify Googlebot](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2006/09/how-to-verify-googlebot.html)

but even if you test for Google and Bing this way, a spambot can enter your site simply by giving a browser user-agent. Therefore, it is ultimately impossible to detect a spam-bot. They are a reality, and there is no good way to keep them out from a web site.

Comment: yes but this script does not care about all spam bots it's just see that a user agent is pretending to be google bot and check if this is really a google bot or not by using gethostbyaddr and gethostbyname

Comment: Why are you having issues with people pretending to be one of the 3 main spiders? Surely this check would just slow *everyone* down with little benefit?

Comment: @hollo I see, that already implements what Google suggest. Hmm, that might should work but making those calls on every request is very expensive. Do you have a real *need* to block spambots?

Comment: @hollo I'd say not really, no. They all access the same public information... And an evil bot will simply try again with a normal IE or Firefox user agent if turned away. (Unless as @Blair says you really have a good reason to tell apart real bots from fake ones.)

Comment: It depends. Do *you* have a reason to check whether it's a real bot? If you don't, then don't bother. If you do, then consider the extra request time for **all** requests and whether that is outweighed by your need to check whether the bot is really a bot.

Comment: I really don't care about checking for spam bots but I read that I need to give the search engines spiders the freedom to crawl my website without sessions and other checking methods that's why I need to know real bots from spam bots

Comment: @hollo you usually don't need to give crawlers any more rights than you give normal users. There are exceptions (like newspapers that let crawlers crawl their stories, but show a paywall to humans) but unless that is your situation, there may not be any need to do anything

Comment: ok so  there is no need to check for bots at all just let them crawl my website as normal users do

Answer (score 0):

you can also have htaccess so that things like this will be prevented just like on this tutorial
http://perishablepress.com/press/2007/06/28/ultimate-htaccess-blacklist/